# iOS add entity to core data from class

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, core-data

I've created an app, and want to add core data functionality.

I have two classes - `project` and `photo`, **is there a way to easily add them to my core data model**. I know it is possible to do the reverse and create a class from an `Entity` in the model.

I'm using Xcode 4.3.

Comment: Not sure why this is down- and close- voted? Seems a reasonable question.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering that too, I wish people would comment to say why they had downvoted. Maybe they are tired of all my iOS questions recently :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in tool that looks at your class and updates the core data model in Xcode.

However, it isn't particularly difficult to do. Assuming these classes are principally used for data storage:

- Remove everything from your class that relates to data storage, leaving only the property declaration.
- Add a @dynamic statement for each property (instead of a @synthesize - this must go).
- Make your object a subclass of NSManagedObject instead of NSObject.
- Add the entities into your data model with the appropriate attributes, and set the class to your modified class.

If you're talking about updating an existing app that is using plists to store, and you want to migrate existing data into your core data store, that is a separate routine you would have to include in your app to run on the first launch of the new version.

Comment: There's no storage at all atm, I've just created the core functionality.

Comment: Just an additional note - images aren't usually best off stored in core data. There's a ton of stuff about that if you search. Usually a path to a stores resource is used instead.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using the ALAssets framework to store images in the user's photo roll :)

Answer (score 0):

Storing an image in Core Data can be as efficient as storing a URL or a file URL. The important step is in Xcode: Check the image data attribute, "Store in external record file".